# Place Divs Side By Side on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal where I would like two sections of data to be side by side. Below is my modal body and the "Data to report" and the "Sort by" sections should be side by side.

In other words, right now it looks like:

[image]

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <h5>Data to report</h5>
  <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
  </div>

  <h5>Sort by</h5>
  <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like them to be side by side. I have tried "float: left" and "display: inline" but these do not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use a div with row, then inside it, two divs with col-xs-6 class?

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! my pleasure. I just added the answer to be more explicit

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Bootstrap markup benefits. You can accomplish what you need doing this

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Half of the modal-body div-->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h5>Data to report</h5>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Other half of the modal-body div-->
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h5>Sort by</h5>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, you'll have both divs side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the header tags inside the divs, and then create a width for the parent(wrapper) div, and then float the divs.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="checkbox">
      <h5>Data to report</h5>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="radio">
      <h5>Sort by</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" class="print-options" value="first_name">First Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal-body {
  width: 750px;
}

.checkbox {
  float: left;
}

.radio {
  float: right;
}
```